# returning a char array from android NDK

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have an issue using the Android NDK to encode a simple CharArray using XOR and it keeps crashing. What's wrong here? Any hints?

Java:

```
public native char[] encrypt(char[] test);
encrypt("test".toCharArray());
```

C++:

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL

Java_com_example_MainActivity_encrypt(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject obj,
        jcharArray value
) {
    jboolean t = JNI_FALSE;
    jchar *carr;
    carr = env->GetCharArrayElements(value,&t);

    for (int i=0; i< (env->GetArrayLength((jcharArray)carr)); i++) {
        carr[i] = carr[i] ^ 'N';
    }

    return (jcharArray)carr;
}
```

Comment: check this out https://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2013/04/jni-jnienv-getchararrayelements-example.html. look at the sample example given at the bottom section

Comment: You can't cast a C array pointer to a Java array type. You'll have to create a new `jcharArray` using the `NewCharArray` method available in your `JNIEnv`.

Comment: The question I linked to is for an `int[]`, but the principle is the same for a `char[]`.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo014